# MS Access VBA import text File

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I am trying to import a text file in MSAccess Vba code as below

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "", "TableName", FileName, True, ""
```

The file am importing does not have a any headers in it. It is a comma delimited file with just data.
The table has column names in it. Now i want to import that file in to this table. When i am trying to import that file using the above code its throwing an error Cannot find col 'X' in the  table .(where X is the first row, first column of data in  in the input file). Please suugest me some solution or a sample example.
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't pass a zero-length string for the optional arguments -- just omit them: `DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "TableName", FileName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file has no headers, you should be passing False for the HasFieldNames parameter instead of True:

> expression.TransferText(TransferType, SpecificationName,
>           TableName, FileName, HasFieldNames, HTMLTableName, CodePage)
>
> ...
>
> HasFieldNames: Use True to use the first row of
>   the text file as field names when importing, exporting, or linking.
>   Use False to treat the first row of the text file as normal data.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220768.aspx